# Add foreign key constraint to DDD modelled owned entity type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am following along a tutorial series on DDD and EF Core, in which several EF Core configuration principles are explained, including owned entity types.

In one example a relation exists between two aggregate roots. However, due to the DDD principles the relation is based upon the id of the related entity, and not the entity itself. Given that these might be in separate services and separate databases this makes sense, I can understand the idea.

But in my simple exercise I know that the entities live in the same service and are on the same database. While I would still like to keep the relationship separate and based on the ids, I would like to model the actual database a bit better.

Given the following, simplified, entities:

```cs
public record DinnerId(Guid Value);
public record GuestId(Guid Value);

public class AggregateRoot<T>
{
    T Id { get; set; }
}

public class Dinner : AggregateRoot<DinnerId> {}

public class Guest : AggregateRoot<GuestId>
{
    private readonly List<DinnerId> _hostedDinners;

    public IReadOnlyList<DinnerId> HostedDinners
        => _hostedDinners.AsReadOnlyList();
}
```

And the entity type configuration looks as follows:

```cs
public class GuestEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Guest>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Guest> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Guests");
        builder.HasKey("Id");
        builder.Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasConversion(x => x, x => new GuestId(x));

        builder.OwnsMany(p => p.HostedDinners, nb =>
        {
            nb.ToTable("GuestsHostedDinners");
            nb.HasKey("Id");

            nb.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("GuestId");
            nb.Property(p => p.Value)
                .HasColumnName("DinnerId")
                .IsRequired();
        });
    }
}
```

When the corresponding SQL migrations are generated, a table `GuestsHostedDinners` is created with 3 columns: `Id`, `GuestId`, and `DinnerId`. As per configuration, a foreign key relation is established from `GuestId` to the `Guests` table on the `Guests.Id` column.

Now, from a relational database point of view it would make sense to also have a foreign key constraint to the `Dinners` table, on the `Dinner.Id` column, as I know that these should be linked. But from a code point of view, using these DDD and owned entity type rules, and limiting the collection to the `DinnerId` entity, how can this constraint be added?

Secondly, an additional `Id` column is added as the link table requires a primary key. But any attempt to simply use a composite key results in an InvalidOperationException, as it cannot find the type to match the `DinnerId` too. Can this also be solved?

*Note: I am not looking into changing the navigation to the `Dinner` entity itself, then it's easy; nor a discussion on that the DDD model and database model should be separate, that is not the goal of this exercise.*

Answer (score 1):

When storing related entities in separate repositories, you can choose to store the "linking data" on either entity.  However at the end of the day EF is a ORM, and requires you to follow some of the relational design principals.

In the relational model links between entities are modeled as foreign key columns, ie the information about who is the Host of a Dinner belongs on the Dinner table, not the Guest table.  And then you don't need a navigation property in your model at all.

```
public class Dinner : AggregateRoot<DinnerId> 
{ 
    private GuestId HostId { get; set; }
}

public class Guest : AggregateRoot<GuestId>
{
}
```

Comment: I understand that, and that's also how I would have modelled it. But in this DDD example there are actually multiple types of Dinners, and each is managed under the Guest, because that is the owner of the type. So I was just wondering if it would be possible to force the constraint coming from the other direction.

Comment: Using a relational database is not mandatory.  And mapping your domain entities directly to your repository is not mandatory.  So sure, you can do whatever you want; it just might add complexity to your application.